# Eclipse undo Ignore

Tags: git, java, eclipse

I have accidentally have clicked onto "Ignore" for one of my class like [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SS1XI.png), now I cannot commit/push it whatsoever.

I have tried `git rm -r --cached .` yet did not work. (I can see the status changed in the bash but in Eclipse it is still ignoring the file, like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTLfy.png))
**Note that Film.java and asd.java is ignored. (asd for was the example)**

What should I do to fix this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you checked the ".gitignore" file that Eclipse should have created under the "domain" subdir? If not, proceed and remove the affecting line (or delete the file if it has a single line). Then Eclipse should take back into consideration your java files.

Comment: I think this would be better suited to our sister site [SO]

Answer (score 1):

In the same folder where the file is located a .gitIgnore file would be created. (Not the main folder. Navigate to the sub folders where the file is located.) In .gitIgnore file remove the required file(s) entry is its only a single file then delete the .gitIgnore file. This is will help in resetting the ignore on the required file.

Comment: That's it! Thx man!

Answer (score 0):

After doing the same, I

- Created a new file and copied the contents into it.
- Added it to the index.
- Deleted the file I accidentally ignored.
- Renamed the new file to the original filename.